# mssql compare two multiple values strings in where clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, where-clause, string-comparison, multiple-value

I want to compare two multiple value strings with each other to see if one of the values exists in the other string.

I have a table with a nvarchar row with pipe separated values, e.g.

> 'value1|value2|value3'

I also have an nvarchar variable with a comma separated string, e.g.

> 'value2,value3'

until now the column in the table had one value, I used a table function to spit the string in the variable and used the IN clause to see if the value was in the generated table. e.g.

```
select * from table1
    WHERE column in (select val from dbo.split(@variable,','))
```

this won't work if the column also contains more values.

```
select * from table1    
    WHERE (select val from dbo.split(column,'|')) in (select val from dbo.split(@variable,','))
```

here it tries to compare 2 generated tables with each other which fails. I have tried this using joins, but can't find a way to properly do this. I'm using MSSQL 2008R2

Comment: It is very bad database design, storing values as CSV or pipe separated values. you should learn about normalization.

Comment: You really should rethink your database design. delimited values in a single column is the wrong thing to do in 99.99999% of the cases.

Comment: If the option to change this from a delimited-list to a normalized table exists, do it now; this is the first bite of a cake of pain.

Comment: I wish I could, this is an application database where I cannot change anything. I do not own the code. and there is no way I can alter the behaviour of the application in this case.

Comment: Then for *each* token in the variable you must run an `IN ()` test against the exploded column (using a pre-created temp table/var)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you:

```
select * from table1 where exists 
(select * from 
    (select val from dbo.split(table1.column,'|')) a,
    (select val from dbo.split(@variable,',')) b 
where a.val=b.val)
```